# IntelliJ Create Custom Warning for Java Class

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I've created an `Either<A,B>` class to represent a sum type. Each instance wraps either an `A` or a `B`. This is represented by extensions `Left<A>` and `Right<B>`. Those types are hidden from the user, and only serve to store the reference to `A` or `B` and implement the abstract methods in `Either`. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
/**
 * A simple SumType implementation. Allows the creation of the Sum Type
 * A + B. Every instance of Either is either (haha.. tomatoes, rocks)
 * an instance of Left, with a value of type A, or an instance of Right,
 * with a value of type B.
 * <br><br>
 * The types and constructors for Left and Right are not exposed.
 * Instead, to construct new instance of Left and Right, the createLeft and createRight
 * methods of class Either should be used.
 * <br><br>
 * The types can be the same, but in that case there isn't much use to using Either.
 *
 * @param <A> The first type to sum
 * @param <B> The second type to sum
 * @author Mshnik
 */
public abstract class Either<A, B> {

  private final boolean isLeft;

  /**
   * Constructs a new Either
   *
   * @param isLeft - true if this is a Left, false if this is a Right
   */
  Either(boolean isLeft) {
    this.isLeft = isLeft;
  }

  /** Creates a Either instance of the given A */
  public static <A, B> Either<A, B> createLeft(A a) {
    return new Left<>(a);
  }

  /** Creates a Either instance of the given B */
  public static <A, B> Either<A, B> createRight(B b) {
    return new Right<>(b);
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if this is a Left, false if this is a Right
   */
  public boolean isLeft() {
    return isLeft;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value of this Either as an an instance of A.
   * If the wrapped value is an instance of B, throws a RuntimeException
   */
  public A asLeft() {
    if (isLeft())
      return ((Left<A,B>)this).getVal();
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the value of this Either as an an instance of B.
   * If the wrapped value is an instance of A, throws a RuntimeException
   */
  public B asRight() {
    if (!isLeft())
      return ((Right<A,B>)this).getVal();
    throw new RuntimeException();
  }

  /**
   * Returns the Object stored within this Either.
   * Should have a stricter type bound (A or B) when implemented by subclasses.
   */
  public abstract Object getVal();

  /**
   * Returns the type of the Object stored within this Either
   */
  public abstract Class<?> getType();

  /**
   * Two Eithers are equal iff:
   * <br>- They are both Left or both Right, the only two direct subclasses
   * <br>- The objects they store are equivalent using Objects.equals.
   */
  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if(this == o) return true;
    if(o == null) return false;
    try {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      Either<A, B> e = (Either<A, B>) o;
      return (!(isLeft ^ e.isLeft)) && Objects.equals(getVal(), e.getVal());
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Hashes an either based on the value it stores.
   * This maintains the hash invariant (two equal objects have the same hashcode),
   * but is not a perfect hashcode because a Left(a) and Right(a) will have the
   * same hashcode but are not equivalent.
   */
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hashCode(getVal());
  }

}
```

The intended use of `asLeft()` and `asRight()` is simple and looks like this:

```
Either<A,B> e = ....; //Take an either reference
if(e.isLeft()) {
    A a = e.asLeft();
    //Handle a
} else {
    B b = e.asRight();
    //Handle b
}
```

And has been extremely useful in the rest of my projects.

Now to my question - I mainly use IntelliJ (and love it), and have noticed that it has a feature that dissuades you from doing things that are likely wrong, such as comparing Strings with `==`.

[image: Warning generated by IntelliJ when comparing strings with ==]

Is it possible to create a custom warning like this for my `Either` class, such that calling `Either::asLeft()` without first checking `Either::isLeft()` will generate a warning? Assuming there is a custom warning capability in IntelliJ (the community edition), does it allow for this type of complexity?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is theoretically possible by developing a plugin. In practise, however, I would advise against doing so, because it may take a lot of effort to implement such checks. However, you could make use of IntelliJ's null checks by altering your class, and creating a method `getLeftOrNull()` which would be marked as `@Nullable` and would return null instead of throwing an exception. Then IntelliJ would warn you if you don't check for null before dereferencing it.

Another option is to use java 8 Optional and create a method `getLeftOptional()` which would wrap the return value and force the caller to handle the case when it is empty (ie. the `Either` is `Right`).